# How to make a image preview after clicking on it like on Blogger.com

Tags: html, css, blogger

I am making a page/site, I really start with my dreamweaver, pure HTML, and CSS. I want to make a image preview like blogger's.

It's like when you click the image on blogger, it brings you to bigger image with transparent background, and there's slide below it. And there's close button on the right corner.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with HTML+Javascript+CSS. You can use some jQuery plugin (jQuery is a JS framework) that is widely used. First link in google for "jquery slideshow" - http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.slider

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but i am sorry before. I'm really new at it. But what I mean is not making a slider, but make an image viewer. like on blogger, for example, on my blogger. https://rullygoodgirl.blogspot.com  when you click image on it. It brings to image viewer.

Comment: I wanna know, can it be used to my website, not blogger.

Comment: Yes. You can use jQuery on your website, there's many tutorials on how to begin.

Comment: Thanks... I found the similar with bloggers :D

Comment: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ this is for example